# Assigning tag to UIButton while loop from array

Tags: ios, uibutton, swift2

How do I assign a unique tag to UIButton while loop from array:

```
var buttonArray: NSMutableArray = ["one", "two", "Three"] // it is a mutable array but for illustration purposes only I put this....
for btnName in buttonArray {

    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,100,100))

    button.layer.masksToBounds = true
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    button.setTitle("\(btnName)", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    //button.tag = ??????

    print(button.tag)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you could use [`enumerate()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_SequenceType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfm/SequenceType/s:FEsPs12SequenceType9enumerateFT_GVs17EnumerateSequencex_). This will create a lazy sequence, containing pairs of elements with their indices.

For example:

```
for (index, btnName) in buttonArray.enumerate() {

    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,100,100))

    ...

    button.tag = index
}
```

Comment: This is actually more elegant to implement

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you can inject some counter.

```
var cnt = 0
for btnName in buttonArray {
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,100,100))
    button.tag = cnt
    cnt += 1
}
```

Comment: I thought ++ was not allowed in swift... I tried cnt+=1 then button.tag = cnt and worked... If you update your answer I will accept it